Can I use function inversion to determine valid input range based on output range, for some vector valued non-linear function?
I'm trying to determine the range of valid inputs for a given function based on its output range. I'm considering the possibility of using function inversion as a method to achieve this. Specifically, I want to know if inverting the function can reliably provide the range of valid inputs corresponding to a given range of outputs.
My function consists of vectors. It might also be non-linear. I'd like to hear from the community if my technique is plausible. If not, what would the downsides be?
Here is a simple example with scalars to demonstrate what I am trying to do -
Let's say we have the function, $y = 1/x$
Then the range of y is, $y \in (y_{min}, y_{max})$
Then the range of x is, $x \in (1/y_{max}, 1/y_{min})$
Regarding my prerequisite knowledge, I have a Masters in Engineering. I'd like to implement this idea for a paper that I am working on. However, I am a little unfamiliar with this area. Please let me know if something is unclear in my question or if further clarification is needed.
